# jQuery crossfade 2 images with thumbnail click

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors, fadein, fadeout

I am trying to make my fadeing in/out more smoother than it currently is here > [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Jwtkf/1/)

Currently it is very sharp (as in it seems to fade the first image out first before the second even begins) when fading images.

The JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#thumbImgs').hoverscroll({
        fixedArrows: true,
        vertical : true,
        width: 250,
        height: 600,
        arrows: false,
        rtl: true,
        thespeed: 30
    });
});

$("#thumbImgs li").live('click', function(e) { 
    var largeImgURL = $(this).attr('id');

    $('#bigPic').fadeOut('fast');
    $('#bigPic').fadeIn('slow').html('<img src="http://www.zzzz.com/test/' + largeImgURL + '" width="1000" height="700" alt="">');
});
```

The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <title>HoverScroll Test Page</title>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://rascarlito.free.fr/hoverscroll/js/hoverscroll/jquery.hoverscroll.js"></script>    
</head>
<body>
    <h1>HoverScroll Test Page</h1>

    <div id="theThumbs">
      <ul id="thumbImgs">
        <li id="img1.jpg"><img src="http://www.zzzz.com/test/img1_tmb.jpg" width="120" height="120" alt=""></li>
        <li id="img2.jpg"><img src="http://www.zzzz.com/test/img2_tmb.jpg" width="120" height="120" alt=""></li>
        <li id="img3.jpg"><img src="http://www.zzzz.com/test/img3_tmb.jpg" width="120" height="120" alt=""></li>
        <li id="img4.jpg"><img src="http://www.zzzz.com/test/img4_tmb.jpg" width="120" height="120" alt=""></li>
        <li id="img5.jpg"><img src="http://www.zzzz.com/test/img5_tmb.jpg" width="120" height="120" alt=""></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="bigPic">
        <img src="http://www.zzzz.com/test/img1.jpg" width="1000" height="700" alt="">
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#thumbImgs').hoverscroll({
            fixedArrows: true,
            vertical : true,
            width: 250,
            height: 600,
            arrows: false,
            rtl: true,
            thespeed: 30
        });
    });

    $("#thumbImgs li").live('click', function(e) { 
        var largeImgURL = $(this).attr('id');

        $('#bigPic').fadeOut('fast');
        $('#bigPic').fadeIn('slow').html('<img src="http://www.zzzz.com/test/' + largeImgURL + '" width="1000" height="700" alt="">');
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally when cross fading occurs it happens between multiple elements. From your example you are trying to crossfade between 1 element.

Check out the following fiddle, it might point you in a good direction. http://jsfiddle.net/Nv6gp/2/

```
$('#thumbImgs').on('click', 'li', fade);

var imgs = $('#imgs li');

function fade(e) {
    var _self = imgs.eq($(e.currentTarget).index());

    imgs.fadeOut();
    _self.fadeIn();
}​
```

Comment: This is more along the lines of what i was looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/Nv6gp/3/

Comment: Ah yeah! Sorry! I could have put the big image in there. I just thought the concept would work.

Comment: @DennisMartinez: Mind updating your code to include the larger images in one DIV instead of all individuality?

Comment: You can't cross fade with one div. Unless you're cross fading children inside that div. Are you asking if I can update the code to be divs instead of ul > li? Sorry, I'm having trouble understanding.

Comment: My original code had a few thumb <img..> and only one "bigPic" <img..> that it changed. That's what i am talking about when i said have it change only one div instead of all those "big" images being loaded at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Is this better? [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jwtkf/2/)

I added the slow `fadeIn` to the callback function of the `fadeOut` animation. This seems smoother to me. You'll have to be a bit more descriptive if this is not what you want.

```
$('#bigPic').fadeOut('fast', function() { 
       $('#bigPic').fadeIn('slow').html('<img src="http://www.zzzz.com/test/' + largeImgURL + '" width="1000" height="700" alt="">');
});
```

Comment: Yes it is better but i was looking for something that allowed the current image to be cross-faded with the new one fading in...

Comment: That means you will have to have both images loaded at the same time. You will need PNGs with transparent backgrounds. Update your code with those types of images and I will show you how.